Solving an equation involving Floor and Ceiling
Trying to see if there is a mathematical expression to represent Floor and Ceilings within an equation and hence subsequently solve it. The one in question is:
$⌊x⌋*⌈x⌉=x^2$       where 0<x<=100,  x is Real
There are actually 199 solutions to this. Beyond the obvious of x--->1,2,...100, there is also √2, and 6√2 and 3√910,....√8930
Do we use arctan representation of Floor to help solve this? I am not sure how to. And for that matter any equation that revolves around these functions.
Thanks!

Consider $~x = P + r ~: ~P \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r < 1.$

Amazing, wow! Thanks @fleablood!  I graphed that and it has the shape of the shifted 1/x function. But how does this heklp find all the radical solutions....

If $x$ is not an integer then $\lceil x \rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$ and so we need to find solutions for $n(n+1) = x^2$ for $\lfloor x \rfloor=n < x < n+1=\lceil x \rceil $.
If we allow that $x = n+m; 0< m < 1$ we have $x^2 = (n+m)^2= n(n+1)$ or $n^2 + 2mn + n^2 =n^2 + n$  so $2mn+m^2 = n$ or $m^2 + 2mn - n =0$.
For any $n > 0; n\in \mathbb Z$ we can solve for $m>0$ via
$m = \frac {-2n \pm \sqrt {4n^2 +4n}}{2}=-n+\sqrt{n^2 +n} $
Now $n=\sqrt{n^2} < \sqrt{n^2 + n} < \sqrt{n^2 + 2n + 1} = n+1$ so $m \in (0,1)$.
ANd that's it.  For every positive integer $n$ there is unique $m\in (0,1)$ where $m = \sqrt{n^2 + n} - n$ and if $x = n + m =  \sqrt{n^2 + n}$ we will have $\lceil x \rceil  \lfloor x \rfloor = n(n+1) = (\sqrt{n^2 + n})^2 = x^2$.
Thus the solutions are $\{n\in \mathbb Z| 0 < n \le 100\}\cup \{\sqrt{n^2+n}|n\in \mathbb Z; 0 < n < 100\}$
=====
Hmmph... in hindsight and the morning after I could have made that a lot simpler.
We need to solve $x^2 = \lfloor x \rfloor \lceil x\rceil$.
Case 1:  $x \in \mathbb Z$.
Then $x = \lfloor x \rfloor =\lceil x\rceil$ and
$x^2 = x\cdot x = \lfloor x \rfloor \cdot\lceil x\rceil$ is always true.
So $x \in \mathbb Z$ will always be a solution (and will be all integer solutions.
Case 2:  $x\not \in \mathbb Z$.
Then $\lfloor x \lfloor < x < \lceil x \rceil$ and $\lceil x \rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor+ 1$.
Let $n = \lfloor x \rfloor$ so that $n < x < n+1$.
Solving $x^2 =  \lfloor x \rfloor \lceil x\rceil$ is a matter of solving:
$x^2 =  \lfloor x \rfloor \lceil x\rceil$
$x^2 = n(n+1)$
$x = \pm \sqrt{n(n+1)}$.
So long as $\lfloor \pm \sqrt{n(n+1)}\rfloor = n$ then $x=\pm \sqrt{n(n+1)}$ will be a solution.
If $x < 0$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$ means $n < x < n+1 \le 0$ so $n < 0$ and $n \le -1$.  Then $n^2 > n^2 + n=n(n+1) > n^2 + 2n +1$ so $|n| > \sqrt{n(n+1)} > |n+1|$ so $n < -\sqrt{n(n+1)} < n+1$.
So for any $n < 0$ then $x = -\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ will give as $n < x < n+1$ and $x$ is a solution.
If if $x > 0$ then $n^2 < n(n+1) < (n+1)^2 \implies n < \sqrt{n(n+1)} < n+1$ so $x = \sqrt{n(n+1)}$ will be a solution.

Thanks @fleablood!  So we have to try all n's 1 by 1 to see if the quare root divides n? ....So if the required range was higher, that will take longer manual time? .... in short is this a manual work at the end?

I think this now becomes a divisibility problem and we need to use Linear Algebra, MOD methods to get a generic solution? ...

I don't understand your comments at all.  For every integer $n$ then $x=n$ and $x=\sqrt{n^2 + n}$ are two solutions and theses solutions exist for all integers.  So the solutions are $1, \sqrt{2}, 2, \sqrt{6}, 3, \sqrt{12}, 4, \sqrt{20}, 5, \sqrt{30}, 6, \sqrt{42},........, 97, \sqrt{97^2 + 97}, 98, \sqrt{98^2 + 98}, 99, \sqrt{99^2 + 99}....., 5013,\sqrt{5013^2+5013}, 5014, \sqrt{5014^2 + 5014}, 5015, .... etc$.  There's nothing more to do or to solve.  And theres nothing to test and try.

Never mind, i mistook the " |n " as "if n divides" ..... whereas you are using it as a seperator to indicate the domain of n.    Ok.

Okay... No, the solutions are either $x$ is an integer $n$ (in which case $x = n = \lfloor x\rfloor= \lceil x \rceil$ and $x^2 = x\cdot x = n\cdot n = \lfloor x\rfloor\lceil x\rceil$).  Of $x=\sqrt{n^2 + n}$ and is not an integer. (And in this case $n < x=\sqrt{n^2 + n} < n+1$ so $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$ and $\lceil x\rceil = n+1$ so $\lfloor x\rfloor \lceil x\rceil = n(n+1) = n^2 +n = x^2$)  Those are all the solutions and they are always solutions.

And the way to solve it is to consider two cases.  Either $x$ is integer and so $x=n=\lfloor x\rfloor=\lceil x\rceil$ and so $x^2 =\lfloor x\rfloor\lceil x\rceil\iff n^2=n\cdot n$ and that is solved by any integer. Or $x$ is not an integer and $\lfoor x \rfloor = n$ for some integer.  $n < x < n+1$ and $\lceil x \rceil=n+1$.  So we want so solve for $x^2 =\lfloor x\rfloor\lceil x\rceil\iff x^2=n(n+1) \iff n^2+n\ge 0; x=\pm\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ which will hold for any integer $n$ (even negative ones)

Yes original message taken - was just a misunderastanding on the notations used.
